# Проблема с Gmail отображение дизайна рассылки

Tags: html, css, frontend, gmail

Добрый День! Столкнулся с проблемой рассылки сообщения, все почтовые сервисы показывают верно верстку и стиль сообщения, только gmail отказывается принимать тег  в начале документа. Есть ли способы решения проблемы?

Comment: Приложите пример кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено. Gmail не принимает шаблоны где весь стиль содержится в начале страницы с тегом `style`. Все стили должны быть прописанны инлайн, то есть непосредственно в каждом элементе.